# System.enqueueJob exception in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, release-notes

I am trying to cover line

`System.enqueueJob(new AsyncCreateExportedTransaction(transactionsSer));`

from test class with version 38 (class version 38), I am facing exception.

**Error Message: System.AsyncException: Maximum stack depth has been reached.**

When I tried this with  test class with version 29 and (class version 33), The line executed without exception.

please let me know any doc/link which states the deprecation of the `System.enqueueJob` from the *test class*

Comment: Please also include the class definition for `AsyncCreateExportedTransaction`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue reported in review, maybe you can upvote it.

- [System.enqueueJob() returns null in Apex tests.](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XJvAAM)

Also refer this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Queueable.htm) which says-

> The ID of a queueable Apex job isn’t returned in test context—System.enqueueJob returns null in a running test.